# Is assigning a singleton to let just for readability?

Tags: swift

If I have a singleton, or even using a system singleton like FileManager or NotificationCenter, should I assign it to a variable instead of just using the full class reference name?
Sometimes I do and sometimes I don't but I was wondering if there are any advantages to assigning to a let.

For example;

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let nc = Notification.default
let ms = MySingleton.shared

ms.getDetails() //vs
MySingleton.shared.getDetails()

or 

fm.moveItem(at: originPath, to: destinationPath) //vs
FileManager.shared.moveItem(at: originPath, to: destinationPath)
```

Obviously assigning to a let makes for shorter references and possibly readability but is that the only reason to do it?

Comment: It depends, if you are not applying dependency injection to make your code testable, there is no difference in how you access the singleton. Otherwise if you use DI, then things quickly change, because it is not recommended to use `MySingleton.shared` everywhere in the code

Comment: For things like `FileManager` where I need to access it several times within a function, I'll assign it to a local variable just for simplicity of typing, but that's me (also agree with Teja)

Comment: If your code directly calls `FileManager.shared.moveItem(...)`, then you can't test that code without needing to actually touch the file system. Even worse when you have a network client that can't be tested without the internet. You just simply shouldn't use singletons, just because they limit what tests you can write.'

Comment: @Alexander. I understand what you’re saying about the limitations and downsides of singletons but in the case of the scenario where I need to actually move files. How else would I do that without using the Filemanager singleton?  I’m genuinely interested.

Comment: @RyanH You'll still use the single instance that Apple provides, but just don't use it in a direct way like you would typically with singletons. For any classes/structs that you have that need to do file operations, make them have a `let fileManager: FileManager`. When that object is constructed, have the file manager be passed into it. You can default the init argument with `fileManager: FileManger = .default`, which is what your production code will use. This gives you the flexibiltiy to pass a fake instance in your tests: `YourClass(fileManager: FakeFileManager())`

Comment: @RyanH That gives you the ability to test `YourClass` without it doing any real reads/writes to the disk. Your `FakeFileManager` can be implement to confirm that "yep, `YourClass` tried to move file `x` from `y` to `z`", without there needing to be any real file `x` or directories `y` or `z`.